# Change SQL Server RDS Instance type from Web to Standard Edition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to change SQL Server RDS Instance from web edition to standard edition. I could see it's not possible from AWS console. Is there any alternate solution? web edition details as follows.

1. DB Engine Version: SQL Server 2014 12.0.0
2. DB Instance Class :m3.large

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following:

- make a snapshot of your instance from console
- find snapshot in list of snapshots in console and choose action restore.
- there will be combo to choose DB engine at the top of Restore DB Instance window. Select edition that you want

Comment: I don't *think* it's this simple.  I'm trying that now (restoring to Standard from a snapshot of a Web edition), and when clicking Restore, i'm getting an error: DBParameterGroup not found: default.sqlserver-se-10.5

Comment: @ilasno When you choose Standard in drop down menu, what is value for parameter group? Maybe you can try to create new parameter group based on sqlserver-se-10.5 and use the group in restoring process